# How to create a IVI driver object with logical name in Python?

Tags: python, driver, instruments

I'm using Python comtypes to get measurement device readings with IVI. We know that for the C-Sharp, there is funtion to create driver with logical name as following:

```
// Create an instance of the session factory
IIviSessionFactory factory = new IviSessionFactoryClass();
// Ask the session factory to create an instance of
// the appropriate driver based on a logical name
IIviScope iviscope = (IIviScope)factory.CreateDriver("MyLogicalName");
```

However, for Python comtypes, it seems we have to create a driver with the program ID directly. Also, we need to initialize the device with the resource name such as 'GPIB0::3::INSTR', so there will be no logical name involved in the case. Every time there should be two inputs for the users to fill in.

```
import comtypes
from comtypes.client import GetModule, CreateObject
from comtypes.gen import IviDmmLib
import pythonnet

GetModule("IviDmmTypeLib.dll")
ivi_dmm = IviDmmLib.IIviDmm.CreateDriver("AgDmm")

my_dmm = CreateObject("Agilent34410.Agilent34410", interface=IviDmmLib.IIviDmm)
# my_dmm = CreateObject("KeithleyDMM7510.KeithleyDMM7510", interface=IviDmmLib.IIviDmm)
# my_dmm = CreateObject("Ag3446x.Ag3446x", interface=IviDmmLib.IIviDmm)

my_dmm.Initialize('GPIB::3::INSTR',False,False,'Simulate=True')
print("Supported instrument models: '%s'" % my_dmm.Identity.SupportedInstrumentModels)
print("Vendor: '%s'" % my_dmm.Identity.Vendor)

my_dmm.configure(Function=IviDmmLib.IviDmmFunctionDCVolts, Range=1.0, Resolution=0.0001)

measured_value = my_dmm.measurement.read(1000)
print(measured_value)
```

So,

1. Does anyone have a solution on this?
2. Since the C-Sharp supports this, could we call the C-Sharp classes with 'pythonnet' package to implement this in python?

I tried to call .NET functions in python but didn't secceed. Does anyone have experience?